# ¿Como juntar los nombres de archivos que se llamen igual pero con distintas extensiones en PHP?

Tags: php, string

Tengo un arreglo con los siguientes nombres de archivos:

```
$lista_archivos[0] = '2019.pdf';
$lista_archivos[1] = '2019.zip';
$lista_archivos[2] = '2018.pdf';
$lista_archivos[3] = '2018.xls';
$lista_archivos[4] = '2019.xls';
$lista_archivos[5] = '2019.xlsx';
```

Lo que busco hacer es agrupar todos los elementos que se llamen igual en un indice de *array*, para así obtener un resultado como este:

```
$archivos_juntos[0] = '2019.pdf-2019.zip-2019.xls-2019.xlsx';
$archivos_juntos[1] = '2018.pdf-2018.xls';
```

El inconveniente que tengo es que no logro idear una función que me permita hacer lo que digo. Intente algo separando los nombres de los formatos, de esta forma:

```
foreach($lista_archivos as $archivo) {
    $archivo = explode('.', $archivo);
    $nombre = $archivo[0];  //Usando echo imprime, por ejemplo: 2019
    $extension = $archivo[1];  //Usando echo imprime, por ejemlo: pdf
}
```

Pero solo llego hasta este punto, no se como debería comparar para que encuentre los otros nombres iguales pero con distinto formato, y que no me los deje repetidos.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo dividiendo la cadena con funciones como `strstr()` para obtener las extensiones, `substr()` y `strrpos()` para obtener los nombres y verificando los indices con `isset()` de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach($lista_archivos as $archivo) {
    $ext = strstr($archivo, '.');
    $nom = substr($archivo,0,strrpos($archivo, '.'));
    isset($archivos_juntos[$nom]) ? 
      $archivos_juntos[$nom].= '-'.$archivo 
      : $archivos_juntos[$nom]=$archivo;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c58d3f31bda187a8f9de5c11d3299a468a25f4d3)</kbd>

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: en la función puede omitirse la linea `$ext = strstr($archivo, '.');`, no es necesaria.

Answer (score 2):

lo que puedes hacer es guardarlos con el nombre en el indice

ejemplo:

```
foreach($lista_archivos as $archivo) {
    $archivoAux = explode('.', $archivo);
    $nombre = $archivoAux[0];  //Usando echo imprime, por ejemplo: 2019
    //$extension = $archivo[1];  //Usando echo imprime, por ejemlo: pdf
    $indice=str_replace(" ", "", $nombre);
    $archivos_juntos[$indice].=(($archivos_juntos[$indice])?"-":"").$archivo;//verifica si tiene datos se le concatena "-"en caso contrario "" y se le concatena el nuevo nombre del archivo
}
```

Comment: Si no es demasiada molestia, ¿Podrías explicarme como funciona la última línea?

Comment: verifica si tiene datos se le concatena "-" en caso contrario "" y se le concatena el nuevo nombre del archivo

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error: Notice: Undefined offset: 2019 | Notice: Array to string conversion in.

Comment: actualice la respuesta , al parecer era por que estaba  convirtiendo el $archivo a un array y lo requería como cadena

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución podría ser la siguiente:

- Usamos [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php) para recorrer el arreglo `$lista_archivos`.
- Usamos [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php) para obtener el nombre del archivo.
- Usamos [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) para saber si el nombre del archivo ya fue agregado al arreglo de resultado

#### Ejemplo:

```
$archivos_juntos = array_reduce($lista_archivos, function ($carry, $file) {
    $name = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
    $carry[$name] = (isset($carry[$name]) ? $carry[$name] . '-' : '') . $file;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

#### Resultado:

```
["2019"=> "2019.pdf-2019.zip-2019.xls-2019.xlsx", "2018"=> "2018.pdf-2018.xls"]
```

Comment: Interesante respuesta, aunque no la pude probar en el http://phptester.net/

Comment: @the-breaker, justamente por eso no puse la demo. `pathinfo` esta desactivada por razones de seguridad